# Office 365 Connects on Mobile, Not on PC

Tags: office365

I'm trying to log in to http://portal.office.com on my PC. If I go there on my phone and enter a zones.com email address, it redirects to the Zones login page. However, if I go there on a PC, Chrome gives me an error saying "The site can't be reached" and ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Neither my phone nor my PC are on any corporate network (phone is connecting through 4g), and I've verified this issue with multiple people and on multiple PCs.

You can try it out, just enter anything @zones.com and it should redirect you to the Zones login page.

Not sure if this is something that can be solved here or if I need to take it up with Zones IT.

Thanks,
 -Vinay

Comment: What does `portal.office.com` have to do with `zones.com`?

Comment: i used portal.office.com as an example, but its really any o365 site that connects with ADFS. you can connect to an o365 site with your company's credentials. it works if i try, for example, a nordstrom.com email. just not with a zones.com email.

Comment: What about other people?  Is this just you or everyone?  Is ADFS using default rules or has it been customized at all?

Answer (score 0):

Just based on your explanation it's something most likely with Chrome.  Did you try another browser (IE,Firefox, etc)?  I can hit the ADFS page - so other browsers will probably work for you.

You can try a few things here to clear up your issue.

1. Check firewall or anti-malware (if other browsers work this probably isn't it, if no browsers work, this is most likely cause)
2. Remove or disable extensions, toolbars, etc.
3. Clear your cache and cookies
4. Flush your DNS (run CMD as administrator and then type ipconfig /flushdns, then ipconfig /renew)
5. Remove and re-install Google Chrome.

Comment: This happens on multiple browsers. (well, at least Chrome and IE)

Comment: Just verified with FF as well.